# Using Jasmine to test object initialization within Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a controller that initializes an object upon initialization of the controller, and would like to test that it was called with the specific params that it is actually called with.

I know that I can test that $scope.autoSaveObj has certain properties that would tell me that it in fact initialized, but how would I spy on the initialization event itself?

Essentially, I want to spy on new autoSaveObj just like I would a method.

The main reason I want to test and spy on the object contructor is so that my karma-coverage plugin will show those lines as covered. It won't show the lines as covered if I just test the state of $scope.autoSaveObject after the initialization.

```
App.controller('ItemCtrl',[ '$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.autoSaveObject = new autoSaveObj({
    obj: $scope.item,
    saveCallback: function() {
                  return $scope.saveItem();
                },
    errorCallback: null,
    saveValidation: $scope.validItem,
    delay: 2000
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the code example is of a partial controller, because properties in the `$scope` are used which are not initialized here.

Since autoSaveObj is not defined anywhere, I assumed it is a global function. Consider moving this to a service or factory instead.

The following example shows how to

- mock `autoSaveObj`
- verify the call parameters, and
- verify that the created instance is actually an instance of the correct type.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).

controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  // Use the injected $window object, so we don't rely on
  // the environment and it can be mocked easily.
  $scope.autoSaveObject = new $window.autoSaveObj({
    obj: $scope.item,
    saveCallback: function() {
      return $scope.saveItem();
    },
    errorCallback: null,
    saveValidation: $scope.validItem,
    delay: 2000
  });
});


describe('ItemCtrl', function() {
  var $controller;
  var $scope;
  var $window;
  var controller;

  beforeEach(module('myApp', function($provide) {
    $window = {
      // Create an actual function that can be spied on.
      // Using jasmine.createSpy won't allow to use it as a constructor.
      autoSaveObj: function autoSaveObj() {}
    };

    // Provide the mock $window.
    $provide.value('$window', $window);
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should instantiate an autoSaveObj', function() {
    spyOn($window, 'autoSaveObj');
    // Initialize the controller in a function, so it is possible
    // to do preparations.
    initController();
    // Do function call expectations as you would normally.
    expect($window.autoSaveObj).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
      saveCallback: jasmine.any(Function),
      delay: 2000
    }));
    // The autoSaveObject is an instance of autoSaveObj,
    // because spyOn was used, not jasmine.createSpy.
    expect($scope.autoSaveObject instanceof $window.autoSaveObj).toBe(true);
  });

  function initController() {
    controller = $controller('ItemCtrl', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/boot.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: I forgot to inject autoSaveObject as a dependency, and yes it is a toned down look at the ctrl